# How to enable print in React application where page rendered as section under <Route>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, slice, react-to-print

I have enabled `react-to-print` module,

```
import { useReactToPrint } from "react-to-print";
```

In the present code from `App.jsx`, `main-presenter.jsx` is been invoked.

```
import MainPresenter, {FLOW_PATH, MEMBER_HOME} from './presenters/main-presenter';
```

And in `main-presenter.jsx`, I have code like,

```
....
export const CONFIRMATION_PATH = '/confirmation';
....
return (
        <React.Fragment>
          .....
          <Route path={CONFIRMATION_PATH} render={() => <SectionPresenter section={confirmationSection} key={confirmationSection} returnToCart={props.returnToCart} openExitModal=
{props.openExitModal}/>}/>
          .....
          </React.Fragment>
         );
```

How I can intricate this  DOM (Route and SectionPresenter) element to place print icon as part of the confirmation page, and for the click, enable the print option.

For printing option, I am referring to the link,- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print

And the code I have is,

```
const dataToPrintRef = useRef();
const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
    content: () => dataToPrintRef.current
});
function printModal({ handlePrint }) {
    printModal.propTypes = {
        handlePrint: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    };
    return (
        <button onClick={handlePrint}>Print</button>
    );
}
....
And in order to block the contect for print, we used,
{ cotentTag.propTypes =
                    ref: dataToPrintRef
                };
```

Comment: Hello. Can you show more of your component please? Where do you pass the `ref` prop to your component?

Comment: This is other stackoverflow forum feed which I have written for the same topic,- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75754955/how-to-create-yup-formik-schema-for-the-print-icon-button

Comment: Can you just share the relevant code in a single place please? I don't see `ref` anywhere in that other thread

Comment: I couldn't make a ref. I have used `window.print()` instead. It made my work simplified.

Comment: `import { selectConfirmationSection } from "../../redux/progress-indicator/progress-indicator-slice";` ... and then `window.print(selectConfirmationSection);` when print button clicked.